# display modal component from other component on Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm pretty new to angular, and I have a modal component with a button, on `(click)` changes the status of the modal from hide to show and it's displayed. however, I want to include this modal on my main component, so I can create a button which displays the modal component over the main component.

this is my **modalLink.ts:**

```
import { Component,Input,trigger,state,style,transition,animate } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'modalLink.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['modalLink.component.css'],
    animations:[
        trigger('Modal',[
            state("show",style({'display':'flex', 'opacity':'1'})),
            state("hide",style({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0'})),
            transition("show <=> hide", animate( "200ms" ))
        ])
    ]
})

export class ModalLink {
    private url:string = '';
    private modal:string = 'hide';

    private objectArea:any = []

    private objectLevel:any = []

    showModal(){
        this.modal = 'show';
    }

    hideModal(){
        this.modal = 'hide';
    }

}
```

and on my **mainComponent.ts** this is an excerpt of what I have:

```
import { ModalLink } from './modalLink.component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'academy.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['academy.component.css']
})

export class AcademyComponent {

    @ViewChild(ModalLink) modalLink: ModalLink

    asdf() {
        this.modalLink.showModal();
      }

}
```

and my **mainComponent.html** which contains the button that calls the asdf function that calls showModal():

```
<div class="container-organize resource-content">
<button (click)="asdf()" class="btn-floating btn-large btn-new-resource"><i class="ai ai-plus"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your situation, you should consider of taking advantage of `Angular-Material`.
Angular Material have implement this for you, just use it this way:

```
import {MdDialog} from '@angular/material';

constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog); // DialogOverviewExampleDialog is another component
}
```

here is simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0J1aSfz2M1x3sPiWeL2g?p=preview)